# How can I use features in statsforecast

Tags: python, time-series, statsforecast

How can I use features in statsforecast (e.g. moving average, lags, user defined function)?

```
fcst = StatsForecast(
    m4_daily_train,
    models = [(auto_arima,7)],
    freq = 'D',
    n_jobs = min(len(m4_daily_train.index.unique()),cpu_count())
)
```

Or is it possible to create the features on my own in a previous step in pandas and use then the total feature table in the fitting like...

```
df['lag1'] = df['y'].shift(1)
df['day'] = df['timestamp'].dt.day

fcst = StatsForecast(
    df,
    models = [(auto_arima,7)],
    freq = 'D',
    n_jobs = min(len(m4_daily_train.index.unique()),cpu_count())
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exogenous variables in the `statsforecast` by passing the training dataset which includes `unique_id`, `ds`, `y`, and `exogenous` variables, and the testing dataset which includes `unique_id`, `ds`, and `future exogenous` variable in the `forecast` step. For more information about Exogenous Regressors, you can find from [official documentation](https://nixtla.mintlify.app/statsforecast/docs/how-to-guides/exogenous.html#introduction)

```py
from datasetsforecast.m5 import M5
from statsforecast import StatsForecast
from statsforecast.models import AutoARIMA

Y_df, X_df, *_ = M5.load('./data')

# Filter data 
Y_ts = Y_df[Y_df['unique_id'] == 'FOODS_3_586_CA_3'].reset_index(drop = True)
X_ts = X_df[X_df['unique_id'] == 'FOODS_3_586_CA_3'].reset_index(drop = True)

X_ts = X_ts[['unique_id', 'ds', 'sell_price', 'snap_CA']]
X_ts['unique_id'] = X_ts.unique_id.astype(str)

# Extract dates for train and test set 
dates = Y_df['ds'].unique()
dtrain = dates[:-28]
dtest = dates[-28:]

Y_train = Y_ts.query('ds in @dtrain')
Y_test = Y_ts.query('ds in @dtest') 

X_train = X_ts.query('ds in @dtrain') 
X_test = X_ts.query('ds in @dtest')

# Add exogenous regressors
train = Y_train.merge(X_ts, how = 'left', on = ['unique_id', 'ds']) 

models = [AutoARIMA(season_length = 7)]
sf = StatsForecast(
    models=models, 
    freq='D', 
    n_jobs=-1
)

fcst = sf.forecast(df=train, h=28, X_df=X_test, level=[95])
fcst = fcst.reset_index()
fcst.head()
```

[image: dataset]